# Error when trying to compile code: "C80: Illegal indirection"

Tags: c, microprocessors, 16-bit

Currently, I am working on an ancient project, and I am trying to fix some errors in order to compile it successfully. I have basic knowledge with c but not enough to fully understand every error in it.

My current problem is that I get the error "C80: '*' illegal indirection", but I don't know why.

Here is the code:

```
/*----------------------------------------------------*/
/*    Generating *lpDes("%23,1f")(float)(word/1000)   */
/*----------------------------------------------------*/
/* Example: 321 --> 32,1                              */
/*----------------------------------------------------*/
void _lWord2Str4f1(LPSTR lpDes, word w)
{
byte b100, b10;

  b100 = w/100;   w -= 100*b100;
  b10 = w/10;     w -= 10*b10;

  if(b100 > 9) {
    *lpDes++ = '*';
    *lpDes++ = '*';
    *lpDes++ = '*';
    *lpDes = '*';
  } else {
//Test !!!!!
    *lpDes++ = (b100 ? '0' + b100 : ' ');
//    *lpDes++ = '0' + b100;
    *lpDes++ = '0' + b10;
    *lpDes++ = *GetText(TEXT_136); // "Error C80: '*' illegal indirection
    *lpDes = '0' + w;
  }
}
```

### Definition of LPSTR GetText

```
/* ------------------------------------------   */
/*               Get Text                   */
/* -------------------------------------------- */
const char far* const far pText_Err = "?";

    LPSTR GetText(word wNr)
    {
        byte bSprache; // Change Language
        LPSTR pText;
    
        bSprache = TestVar.bLaendereinstellung; // Test !!! neu 08.03.2002
    //  bSprache = 0;
    
        pText = (LPSTR)pText_Err; /* Default */
        if (wNr < D_MaxText) {
            switch(bSprache) {
              #if(SPR_EINB_D == TRUE)
                case SP_D:   pText = (LPSTR)pText_D[wNr];   break;
              #endif

              #if(SPR_EINB_F == TRUE)
               // case SP_F:   pText = (LPSTR)pText_F[wNr];   break;
              #endif

              #if(SPR_EINB_E == TRUE)
                 case SP_E:   pText = (LPSTR)pText_E[wNr];   break;
              #endif
                default: pText = (LPSTR)pText_D[wNr];
            }
        }
        return (LPSTR)pText;
    }
```

### TEXT_136

```
#define TEXT_136        136
```

### pText_D

```
const char far* const far pText_D[] =
{
  szText000, szText001, szText002, szText003, szText004,
  szText005, szText006, szText007, szText008, szText009,

  szText010, szText011, szText012, szText013, szText014,
  szText015, szText016, szText017, szText018, szText019,

  szText020, szText021, szText022, szText023, szText024,
  szText025, szText026, szText027, szText028, szText029,

  szText030, szText031, szText032, szText033, szText034,
  szText035, szText036, szText037, szText038, szText039,

  szText040, szText041, szText042, szText043, szText044,
  szText045, szText046, szText047, szText048, szText049,

  szText050, szText051, szText052, szText053, szText054,
  szText055, szText056, szText057, szText058, szText059,

  szText060, szText061, szText062, szText063, szText064,
  szText065, szText066, szText067, szText068, szText069,

  szText070, szText071, szText072, szText073, szText074,
  szText075, szText076, szText077, szText078, szText079,

  szText080, szText081, szText082, szText083, szText084,
  szText085, szText086, szText087, szText088, szText089,

  szText090, szText091, szText092, szText093, szText094,
  szText095, szText096, szText097, szText098, szText099,

  szText100, szText101, szText102, szText103, szText104,
  szText105, szText106, szText107, szText108, szText109,

  szText110, szText111, szText112, szText113, szText114,
  szText115, szText116, szText117, szText118, szText119,

  szText120, szText121, szText122, szText123, szText124,
  szText125, szText126, szText127, szText128, szText129,

  szText130, szText131, szText132, szText133, szText134,
  szText135, szText136, szText137, szText138, szText139,

  szText140, szText141, szText142, szText143, szText144,
  szText145, szText146, szText147, szText148, szText149,

  szText150, szText151, szText152, szText153, szText154,
  szText155, szText156, szText157, szText158, szText159,

  szText160, szText161, szText162, szText163, szText164,
  szText165, szText166, szText167, szText168, szText169,

//  szText170, szText171, szText172, szText173, szText174,
//  szText175, szText176, szText177, szText178, szText179,
};
```

### Defintions

```
typedef char far*       LPSTR;
```

I have zero clue what this code does as it is part of an ancient operating system for a 16-bit microprocessor.

I've did a bit of research and some suggested changing the error part from `*lpDes++ = *GetText(TEXT_136);` to `lpDes++ = *GetText(TEXT_136);` but I don't know if this is possible or a good idea.

How can I change the code without changing its logic?

Comment: Do you have the definition of `GetText`?

Comment: `GetText` should return a char (const) pointer, and it probalby doesn't. Without the definition of `GetText()` who knows?

Comment: What does GetText do?

Comment: I've added the definition, but can't say what it really does

Comment: What is `TEXT_136`? Also, you have some other undefined variables in your code - please post everything needed to reproduce your error.

Comment: I'm trying to post everything in order to understand the error

Comment: GetText obviously retuns a language specific string (I would assume German (D), French (F) and English(E)). For the problem at hand it is irrelevant what GetText does, only the definition is important. So the question is, how LPSTR is defined.

Comment: @Devolus Yeah you are right, the guys who programmed this os told me about something similar.

Comment: Ok, `GetText` should return a `char *` so the line should not raise that error. Have you a *declaration* of `GetText` in this compilation unit. When the compiler finds no declaration for a function, it could assume that it returns an int value, which would be consistent with the raised error. Or you failed to declare (still in this compilation unit) that `LPSTR` is `char *`...

Comment: Did you include or define a prototype of GetText()? For ancient systems this might have not been done. If not, then add a protoype like this before the code `LPSTR GetText(word);`

Comment: `LPSTR GetText(word)` is defined in `LANGUAGE.c` but never imported inside the above given code. Would I resolve this error when I create an "LANGUANGE.h" header file and import it into the given code?

Comment: Then this is most likely your problem. The compiler doesn't know the definition of `GetText()` and assumes int as return value. For modern compilers this should at least raise a warning or even an error, but if you haven't seen this, then it might not do it. You can either create an include file with the prototype (as I said above) which I would recommend, or just put the proto in top of your module.

Comment: Thanks @Devolus this resolved my problem. I've added a header file and now it works!

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code , this is what I can deduce

There is a function to convert and long integer (also called as a lword) to string.

```
void _lWord2Str4f1(LPSTR lpDes, word w)
```

if you input 321 you should store 32,1 //notice ,

You first get teh base 100, base 10 and base 1 (stored in w)

Then just add the ascii value of '0' to b100, b10 and b1 to convert it to a ascii character

so below line should just give yo ascii value of ,

```
*lpDes++ = *GetText(TEXT_136);
```

maybe ascii value of 136 is ,.
Update:

Ohh.. The problem seems to be that the assignment discards the "const" qualifier.
This may be okay with some compilers, while some just let go it with a warning.

- May be there could some compiler options you can change to get
  around. GCC doesn't seem to much care. and gives only a warning if
  you assign const pointer to a variable pointer.
- Or try adding explicit casting
  `*(LPSTR)lpDes++ = *(LPSTR)GetText(TEXT_136);`

Here's an example to make this clear (this might be still legal and valid under some compilers like gcc)

This can be better explained with an example:

See below,

```
int * pointer;
int * const const_pointer = &var;
const int * pointer_to_const;

/* a */
pointer = const_pointer; // OK, no cast (same type)

/* b */
pointer_to_const = pointer; // OK, casting 'int*' to 'const int*'

/* c */
pointer = pointer_to_const; // Illegal, casting 'const int*' to 'int*'
```

I hope you understood.

Comment: added the definiton

Comment: Please see the update: section in my response. I think the solution could be to get compiler options right or try with different type castings.